# TypeError: Cannot call method "getThreads" of null

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm getting a "cannot call method" error on this, when I'm pretty sure it should be fine...

```
function cleanUp() {
  var delayDays = 2
  var maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays);
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Inbox");
  var threads = label.getThreads(0, 50);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
    {
    threads[i].moveToTrash();
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Inbox");
var threads = label.getThreads(0, 50);
```

Try using

```
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 50);
```